# Batch class run after press button

Tags: apex, batch

I need to create a batch that automates the creation of Cases from a Campaign by taking only the members related to a campaign that are in 'To send' status.
(this batch should run after pressing a button in a campaign object and process that particular campaign)

Each campaign can have related different members.

my draft code :

```
global class CreateRicontatto implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    
    
    global Database.QueryLocator start (Database.BatchableContext BC){
        
        String id = '7010J000001HCkjQAG';
        String query = 'SELECT Campaign.Id, Status, Campaign.Type__c, Campaign.Subject__c, Name, Campaign.Data_Chiamata__c, Campaign.Description FROM CampaignMember WHERE Campaign.Id :=id';
         
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
            
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<CampaignMember> scope){
        List<Case> ricontatto = new List<Case>();
        
        For(CampaignMember c : scope){
            
            if(c.Status == 'To Send'){
                
                Case casi = new Case();
                casi.RecordTypeId = '0120Y000000FbCuQAK';
                casi.Campaign__c = c.Campaign.Id;
                casi.Type = c.Campaign.Type__c;
                casi.Description = c.Campaign.Description;
                casi.Subject = c.Campaign.Subject__c;
                casi.DataChiamata__c = c.Campaign.Data_Chiamata__c;
                ricontatto.add(casi);
            }
            
        }
        If(ricontatto.size()>0)
            insert ricontatto;
          
    }
global void finish (Database.BatchableContext BC){
}
}
```

thank you for any help.

Comment: What's your question? You've provided some code, but I'm not sure where you're stuck?

Comment: I would like to know if it would be possible to run this batch every time I press a button in campaign object, should not be scheduled, but should start every time I click the button.

My code currently is the one posted above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the following options available in Salesforce:

- [Quick Action](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.actions_overview.htm&type=5) that uses an Aura or Lightning Web Component

  - Can be with a modal ([LWC](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_quick_actions)/[Aura](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:lightningQuickAction/documentation)) or headless ([LWC](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_quick_actions_headless)/[Aura](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader/documentation))
  - Object-Specific Quick Action that calls a Flow to call [Apex Invocable Method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm)
- [Custom Button or Link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_define_custom_buttons.htm) that uses:

  - Visualforce
  - Aura (via [lightning:isUrlAddressible](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:isUrlAddressable/documentation))
  - [Apex Invocable Method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm) called from a Flow

There are various variants for each option, it really depends on how you want the user to interact with the server. I apologize for the link-heavy answer, but the main takeaway here is that there are easily half-a-dozen different approaches that you can take that are all valid alternatives. It is up to you to decide which method would be the most appropriate for your situation.

Comment: Also: object-specific quick action+screen flow +invocableApex.

Comment: @cropredy Thanks! I had a feeling I forgot something.

Comment: If the Quick Action is required in Mobile than Aura is only option as LWC components are not yet supported in Salesforce mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you can create a **quick action button** in Campaign Object & call an LWC or an Aura component from it.

And then you can Create an Apex Controller class "ControllerClass" and create a method "callBatch" in that class which will call the batch class.

Then, the call the "callBatch" from Aura or LWC Controller. **I hope you know how to call the apex method from Aura or LWC.**

To pass the current record id you can pass it from LWC or Aura to the Apex Method "callBatch".

Refer to this for quick action in LWC - [Quick Headless Action](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_quick_actions_headless)
Refer to this for calling Apex from LWC - [Call Apex Methods Imperatively](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/apex_call_imperative)